# What syntax allows me to multiply numbers in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following data as an example:

1. Time per item: `0.30 min`
2. No.of items: `3`

So, what syntax allows me to calculate the correct hours and minutes (hh:mm)?

Comment: For now, your question is quite unclear. You should try to give more details on your problem.

Answer (score 4):

To calculate the time properly in excel is to make sure that the cell used is formated as "time" then the program will recognise it as time, and get all the numbers correct for calculating time.  Until such time we switch to the metric time system with 100 time units in each longer time unit :-)

http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=136187
http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/538480-multiply-hours-minutes-by-cost-hour-to-get-total-cost.html

From the link where **BoniM** says

> =A1*B1*24   - this formula does the math correctly without you having to multiply  the minutes into a fraction first as long as the
>   cells remain formated as  time. Don't change the format to general or
>   if it is general, change it to  the time format. (Format, cells, time,
>   choose 37:30:55).

-----------------------------Side notes---------------------

If you have any reason to convert to decimal time this link shows one method simply.
http://www.consultdmw.com/excel-time-conversion.htm

=INT(A2)*24+HOUR(A2)+ROUND(MINUTE(A2)/60,2)

Answer (score 3):

You can find [help about Excel online](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/), typing in `multiply numbers` gives [multiply numbers](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/multiply-numbers-HP010342714.aspx?CTT=1).

> To do this task, use the * (asterisk) arithmetic operator.
>
> For example, if you type =5*10 in a cell, the cell displays the result, 50.

If you use different cells, you can use their cell names, like so: `=A1*A2`

For instance, if that would be the equation put into A3. Then `A1 = 0.3, A2 = 3, A3 = 9`.

*Make sure that third column is the format in which you want your data to be...*